# What code to use for decoding intent strings?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I have an musicplayer app that gets music from uri. How can I get Track and Artist name from it? intent.getStringExtra() doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how to solve this problem ?

For closer example. I use that intent.getStringExtra() and what I got is the file's path. And if it's named like "iosbadfipduva.mp3" I got that name not name like Shakira Waka Waka. But when I open it in other file explorer like ES file explorer it shows the name properly. How did they did it? And one last question. How to retrieve artwork from that uri ?

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question correctly, once you have the uri you can the trackID from it and query for all the details associated with that trackID

```
String selection="DISTINCT " + MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID+"trackID";
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};
Cursor songDetails = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,selection, null, null);
```